# Django-Form: Problem with adding additional information to form while cleaning it

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I've got a Django form which simply takes a zip-code.

```
class ServiceAreaForm(forms.Form):    
name = forms.CharField(disabled=True, required=False)
    zip = forms.IntegerField(
        label="PLZ", validators=[validateZipCodeLength]
    )
def clean(self):
    service_area: ServiceArea = validateServiceArea(self["zip"].value())
    self.fields["name"].value = service_area.name
    super().clean()
```

In validateServiceArea, I would like to check the zip code is supported.

```
def validateServiceArea(zip_code):
try:
    return ServiceArea.objects.get(zip=zip_code)
except ServiceArea.DoesNotExist:
    raise ValidationError("Not supported Service Area")
```

If so, I would like to pass the information in my returned ServiceArea on to another form, instead of using another query for the same thing.

I've been trying using the clean method of the form and put it in the name-field, but it just feels too complicated (and name won't even appear in cleaned_fields).

Is there any easy way doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do it this way:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super.clean()
    service_area: ServiceArea = validateServiceArea(cleaned_data.get("zip"))
    cleaned_data["name"] = service_area.name
    return cleaned_data
```